# From where a control(Say, a Button) gets its width in a Layout Panel(Stackpanel) in case it is not explicitly set?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I am currently learning WPF and during this I came across HorizontalAlignment/VerticalAlignment Properties that can be set for a control and determines that where a control will be placed in a Layout control when there is extra space is available.
Now, I was looking into following code block:

```
<StackPanel>
    <Label HorizontalAlignment="Center">A Button Stack</Label>
    <Button HorizontalAlignment="Left">Button 1</Button>
    <Button HorizontalAlignment="Right">Button 2</Button>
    <Button>Button 3</Button>
    <Button>Button 4</Button>
</StackPanel>
```

Now, when I place this code in a window and execute, It is displayed like this:
[Horizontal/VerticalAlignment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y5l6h.png)

My Query is: From where does the width of Button1 and Button2 is determined since I have not set and width property for those controls?

Answer (score 0):

Default behavior of `StackPanel` is to stack the controls vertically and `HorizondalAlignment` of the items will be `Stretch` and vice versa if you switch the `Orientation`.

On setting the `HorizontalAlignment` to `Left` or `Right` leads to make the control to have their `Width` as designed.

**To answer your question** on `Width` of the `Button`, the default template of the `Button` is designed in such a way as

```
 <Border x:Name="border" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
     <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" Focusable="False" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
 </Border>
```

`Border` has the default capability to adjust its `Width` based on the `Content` it holds.

In your case, the `Content` is a text *"Button 1"* which occupies some `width` and that will be the `width` of the `Button`